# Spring boot internalization and exceptions

Tags: spring, exception

I'm making an API using Spring boot and trying to making it suit many languages, to do so i'm using this code :

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return slr;
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}

@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    String[] baseNames = { "messages/messages", "messages/messages_errors" };
    source.setBasenames(baseNames);
    source.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
    return source;
}
```

So logically in my controller i get the lang parameter to know which language the user has chosen and it works great.
The problem is that i'm throwing an exception from a method called by the controller, here is the code :

```
public User getUser(final Long pIdUser) throws EntityNotFound {
    User vUser = userRepository.findOne(pIdUser);

    if (vUser == null) {
        throw new EntityNotFound("entity.notFound.byId", new Object[] { pIdUser });
    }

    return vUser;
}
```

and i'm using a @ControllerAdvice to get the exception and switch the exception message to the right language like that :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @ExceptionHandler(value = EntityNotFound.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    protected EntityNotFound EntityNotFound(EntityNotFound pException, Locale lang) {
        return new EntityNotFound(messageSource.getMessage(pException.getMessage(), pException.getArgs(), lang));
    }
```

But i can't have the right message, i have "entity.notFound.byId" in the response of the controller. Someone knows how to deal with internationalization and errors ?

I think that if i make the lang variable as globale, i could have the right message at the first call of the EntityNotFound exception but i will have to set lang in every controller and it's dirty.

Thank you for your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested by the solution, i did that using a global variable which stores the language to use : `public static Locale LANG = Locale.ENGLISH;` and created my own LocaleChangeInterceptor class to set LANG variable with the given language from the request.